# Video streaming using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, video, mp4

Alrighty so since the Class I was looking at isn't for remote files but instead is for local files.. I decided to do some searching and found this cURL code that seems promising to actually play REMOTE URI's

```
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($path, TRUE));
    $filesize = $head['content-length'];

    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $path); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, max (0, $filesize - 128) . '-' . max (0, $filesize - 1));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);

    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
    echo $content;
```

This is what I got so far, I copied most of the headers from the class from before and I also am now using cURL for this.. I do get the same result which is just a black player, playing.

And here is the response I get when I `echo $content`

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 06 May 2016 23:56:18 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 128
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 May 2016 19:07:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "572ceb68-75445cb"
Expires: Fri, 13 May 2016 23:56:18 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Cache-Control: public
Content-Range: bytes 122963275-122963402/122963403
```

Comment: Try to display errors, check error_log, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I actually did get something in the logs saying `filesize(): stat failed` and I'm starting to think it failed because it's a Remote URI and not a file on the server possibly?

Comment: It seems this library only accept local file or Amazon S3.

Comment: Well that's a bit disappointing, do you notice any code that can have a workaround to allow remote URI's?

Comment: So I fixed the "filesize" error and managed to make a workaround with it, but now I'm stuck on fseek... How would I use a remote URI to get around it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with this library. You can cURL this video, save locally and stream.

Comment: I don't want to save it locally though, I should be able to grab the file remotely can I not?

Comment: Kk updated Topic with new code, kind of turned the topic around now with this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a remote URL, check your server allows fopen to open remote files.
allow_url_fopen needs to be enable in your php.ini

Comment: It is already enabled, that's not the issue. It seems the actual class itself is for local files.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Strange, because you have the die message which indicates fopen doesn't work as intended.

Comment: My die message indicates filesize doesn't work and fseek, whatever that is. My fopen works fine